# Acoustic treatment - Bass Traps w/o drywall?

Tags: acoustics, room-treatment

I'm about to frame/drywall a room approximately 18 x 14 x 9 and acoustically treat it.
I plan on using rockwool insulation for its acoustic properties, fire/waterproofing etc...

It's my understanding that bass traps that run from floor to ceiling in the corners of the room would need air gaps behind them and therefore take up a lot of space inside the room once the drywall's installed. I would like to save this valuable space if possible.

Would there be anything wrong about not drywalling the corners of the room (stopping the drywall at the previous stud?) and then using the exposed rockwool that's inside the frame as the bass trap?

Ideally I'd like to cover the exposed rockwool with breathable cloth.  I feel that would wisely save space and use the soundproofing materials already inside the framing (instead of buying more and additionally putting it outside of the drywall). I hope that this could create an additional advantage by allowing different 'swappable faceplates' (that would consist of different materials) to cover the rockwool, in case the room feels too absorptive.

Acoustically would this work or is there some flaw in doing so?

Thanks!

Comment: It is slightly unclear what you plan on doing. Maybe you can elaborate a little. Most important is that there is difference between 1) acoustic treatment of a room and 2) sound insulation. If 2 is what you are after, basically the room will have to be totally air tight with heavy materials in walls, ceiling and floor. I highly recommend adding sound insulated air inlets and outlets. In 1) you do whatever works. Not having dry wall towards the inside of the room absolutely works as long as the integrity of the walls is taken care of, maybe adding som extra studs.

Comment: Yeah I'm more interested in acoustical treatment and less interested in soundproofing (though it's a nice-to-have)

Answer (score -1):

No drywall is Ok as far as acoustical treatment. The other effects you may want to achieve by the drywall, if any, will of course not happen.